# How can I prove this kind of reverse Jensen's inequality?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

$$f(\lambda_1x_1+...+\lambda_nx_n)\ge\lambda_1f(x_1)+...+\lambda_nf(x_n)$$

*f* is a convex function and
Conditions are as follows:
$$\lambda_1\gt0 ,  \lambda_i\le0, \lambda_1+...+\lambda_n=1$$

Comment: If Jensen's inequality gives you precisely the *opposite* result, why do you expect your version to be true?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The difference is in the conditions. All λ1 to λn are positive for Jensen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the conditions you actually have $\lambda_1 = 1+ \sum_{j\geq 2} (-\lambda_j)\geq 1$ or $1= \frac{1}{\lambda_1} +  \sum_{j\geq 2} \frac{-\lambda_j}{\lambda_1}$ (sum of non-negative elements). Write $x_0=\sum_{j\geq 1}\lambda_j x_j$. Then
 $$ x_1 =  \frac{1}{\lambda_1} x_0 +  \sum_{j\geq 2} \frac{-\lambda_j}{\lambda_1} x_j $$
and by Jensen (usual):
$$f(x_1) \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_1} f(x_0) +  \sum_{j\geq 2} \frac{-\lambda_j}{\lambda_1} f(x_j)$$